# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Only for app center built

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, capacitor, visual-studio-app-center

There are many questions with the error message like mine but I couldn't find any proper solution for me.

I have a mobile app and I have been using ionic framework with [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0) in version 2. I decided to migrate to version 3 and everything works fine locally on android and ios. The only issue I have is when I wanted to build my app with [app center](https://appcenter.ms/). Android version is built without any issues but iOS built throws me an error like below:

```
ld: framework not found CapacitorApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and somewhere below is the error code:

```
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

I dont know if it helps you but below you can find my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode 10 caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorApp', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/app'
  pod 'CapacitorAppLauncher', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/app-launcher'
  pod 'CapacitorBrowser', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/browser'
  pod 'CapacitorDevice', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/device'
  pod 'CapacitorHaptics', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/haptics'
  pod 'CapacitorKeyboard', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard'
  pod 'CapacitorPushNotifications', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/push-notifications'
  pod 'CapacitorSplashScreen', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/splash-screen'
  pod 'CapacitorStatusBar', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/status-bar'
  pod 'CapacitorStorage', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/storage'
  pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  pod 'CordovaPluginsResources', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
end
```

Unfortunately I cannot shouw you all of my code but if you need any peace of it just tell me in the comment.

update:
I was able to reproduce it locally. It is happening only on `App staging` schema. The other one `App` looks good.

[image: xcode build result screenshot]

Comment: Does app center allow you to run commands before build? you should run `npm run build` and `npx cap sync ios` before doing the native build.

Comment: Not sure. However since yesterday I was able to reproduce the issue locally. I have 2 instance of my app. `App` and `App Staging` and everything is working fine on `App` instance but `App staging` shows me an error I posted in my question. Not sure what is the difference between the instances. For sure I am missing something but I cannot figure out what I missed there.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 instance"?

Comment: Sorry I was not precise. I have 2 schema configurations(?) like [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-development-staging-and-production-configs-in-xcode-ec58b2cc1df4).

Comment: then add ```target 'App Staging' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
end``` to your Podfile

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple schemas you need to add them to the `Podfile` so they can use Capacitor plugins

```
target 'App Staging' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you run npx cap sync after adding that? You should not remove the App entry or then that scheme will break, you should have an entry per scheme.

Comment: Yes I did. I am not sure if I understand you. I have an entry per scheme.

Comment: In your last screenshot I can see the Podfile and on line 26 there is a blue mark, which means you have edited that line, probably from "App" to "App Staging". And I can't see another block for the "App" scheme on the screenshot, maybe you didn't capture the whole Podfile, but it looks like you only have the "App Staging" entry.

Comment: Yep I edited it like you've said. When I add another block(in podfile) with `App` it shows me an error on `npx cap sync ios`. The error message is `Unable to find a target named 'App Staging' in project 'App.xcodeproj', did find 'App'.`. However inside `App.xcodeproj` folder I have files called `App.xcscheme` and `App Staging.xcscheme`. Shouldn't it be correct then?

Comment: A target and a scheme are different things, you need both, a target called App Staging with a scheme also called App Staging. What I do is to right click the App target from Xcode and select duplicate, then rename it. Since the App target already had a scheme, duplicating it also makes that the duplicated target already contains a scheme

Comment: Wow this is so confusing. I duplicated it, `npx cap sync ios` passed but when I try to build  **App Staging** on the xcode I have the same error `Framework not found CapacitorApp`. **App** build is working fine like previously.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found the solution. For some reason, I had to copy and paste the list of frameworks in `Frameworks Search Paths`. It was filled in **Debug** and **Release** schema but for **Staging Debug** it was empty. Here is the screenshot with what I had to add.
[image: filled framerowks search paths]